# Spacing the itemize content

Tags: spacing, itemize

Is there any way to change horizontal align for the itemize? I tried to use `\hspace{-0.5cm}{\begin{itemize}...}`, however, it did not work.

Comment: Could explain what exactly you try to obtain?

Comment: See `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 2):

The horizontal alignment can be influenced by changing the `leftmargini` length:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\end{itemize}

\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it one of these layouts that you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt]
\item abc. Blah blah blah blah… Blah blah bla blah… Blah blah blah blah… Blah blah blah blah… Blah blah blah blah…
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
\item abc. Blah blah blah blah… Blah blah bla blah… Blah blah blah blah… Blah blah blah blah… Blah blah blah blah…
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]